# Regular expression to extract text in reverse order until 3rd instance of a character

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in the format `XXXX_YYYY_YYYYYYY_YYYYYYZZZZ`

How can I extract the string from backwards, until the thrid `_` (underscore) is hit.
extracted value: `YYYY_YYYYYYY_YYYYYYZZZZ`

I tried this `((?:_[^_]*){3})$` and it seem to work with extra `_` in the beginning  which I can probably remove it in Java.

Is there any way I get get with out the `_` in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
        String line = "XXXX_YYYY_YYYYYYY_YYYYYYZZZZ";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^_]+(?:_[^_]*){2})$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

Simply split your "three-times" {3} into one instance without _ and two that need it.

Answer (score 5):

This one should suit your needs:

```
[^_]+(?:_[^_]+){2}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TAW_0myLB7pBHWRN)

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse the string first, then you can get away with a very simple regex of `(.*)(_.*)`:

```
String input = "XXXX_YYYY_YYYYYYY_YYYYYYZZZZ";
input = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString().replaceAll("(.*)(_.*)", "$1");
input = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
YYYY_YYYYYYY_YYYYYYZZZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex approach is also possible:

```
String s = "XXXX_YYYY_YYYYYYY_YYYYYYZZZZ";
List r = Arrays.asList(s.split("_"));       // Split by _ and get a List
r = r.subList(Math.max(r.size() - 3, 0), r.size()); // Grab last 3 elements
System.out.println(String.join("_", r));    // Join them with _
// => YYYY_YYYYYYY_YYYYYYZZZZ
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/FCnmtZ)

In case there are less than 3 elements after splitting, just the remaining ones will get joined (i.e. `XX_YYY` will turn into `XX_YYY`).

Answer (score 0):

For a performance issue, it is better to use regex rather than String split. The answer of Jan is what you need.